# How to view resource allocation to specific projects

Tags: ms-project, resources

In MS Project, I've created a resource pool which is shared amongst several projects, can I see how much time a certain resource is allocated to a certain project?
Alternatively, is there a way to allocate a certain percentage of time for each resource to each individual project where they have a different amount of time for each project?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Resource usage view to the resource pool file.  Add the Project field to the view.  You can them create a group to group first by Name and then group the assignments by Project.  Regarding different allocations to each project, no sorry.  The max units is for the resource - not allocation per project.